# What type of hybridization does phosphorus have in P2O5?

Tags: orbitals, hybridization

I'm inclined to think that P has a $dsp$ hybridization in that compound, because it makes 5 bonds and 2 of them are $\pi$ bonds - with oxygen. However, I found in some websites that it may have $sp^2$ hybridization, although I have no idea how could it be possible - since it has to make two $\pi$ and 3 sigma bonds.

Comment: [Welcome to chemistry.SE!](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) If you had any questions about the policies of our community, please ‎visit [the help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). || It's better to ask two separate questions in two separate threads.

Comment: There is only one pi bond to oxygen and four sigma bonds per a phosphorus atom: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phosphorus_pentoxide#/media/File:Phosphorus-pentoxide-2D-dimensions.png

Comment: @Marko and even that $\pi$-bond is not neccessarily there...

Comment: It has a significant pi character as can be seen by the different bond length between the C=O and C-O bonds.

Comment: It's normal sp3 like in phosphoric - there should dative bond  to describe it properly not double.